# CAPTCHA solver in ruby?

Tags: ruby, captcha

I'm trying to get through a [simple catpcha](http://cl.ly/image/1s2h19013m3k) for rather unharmful purposes (checking my food voucher credit). I'm looking for a Ruby library which could solve simple captchas as those. Is there any available?

Comment: Maybe you can just ask your company to offer a simple API for that? Maybe even offering your assistance with implementing it.

Comment: @tessi, do you really think a company that protects their data with captcha is interested in handing it out to whoever asks? Use your brain.

Comment: It all depends on the people involved, but it cannot hurt to ask and offer help. Especially because an API might even improve the service they offer. Just trying to use my brain here ;) If, as you say, the company tries hard to "protect" its data, then circumventing the protection is at least questionable (in a law-related way of seeing things).

Comment: It's a stupid food voucher company in Brazil. If they ever reply, it will probably be a scripted answer. I can assure that no one that has ever cared will get my answer. Trust me, I've tried this over and over several times. :)

Comment: @tessi, thanks for your feedback but violating a websites ToS, while it might be morally questionable, is not likely to violate any actual national laws, and even if that were the case. it's really not your job to police them.

Comment: Disclaimer: The site doesn't even have a ToS: https://sodexosaldocartao.com.br/saldocartao/consultaSaldo.do?operation=setUp

Comment: @PedroNascimento Does my answer match your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [easy_captcha_solver](https://github.com/alex-rodriguez/easy_captcha_solver) : A captcha solver for very simple captcha, requires `tesseract-ocr` and `mechanize`.
- [CaptchaBreaker](https://github.com/eidge/ruby-captcha-breaker) : ruby captcha solver, requires `rmagick` and `rtesseract`.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of webservices for solving captchas. Deathbycaptcha.com has a ruby gem and seems to be the most popular.